# Websockets (Sockjs-client) : net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: websocket, cross-domain, sockjs

I'm making a connection to a socket server :

```
  var sock = new SockJS('http://hostname:9090/ws');
```

And the server is a remote machine. The connection doesn't happen and it throws this error.

As I understand I would need to set a cross origin header while creating the connection, but I am not sure how to do it. Any suggestions how to set the header OR if that's not the problem here then what's going on ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED normally means that there is no server running at the address you provided. It would not be caused by your headers being incorrect.